# Is it possible to put a 1D ndarray (size N) into 1D ndarray (size N,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to put results of a calculus into a big matrix where the last dimension can be 1 or 2 or more.
so to put my result in the matrix I do

```
res[i,j,:,:] = y
```

If y is sized (N,2) or more than 2 it is find, but if y is sized (N) I got an error saying:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10241) into shape (10241,1)
```

Small example:

```
import numpy as np

N=10
y = np.zeros((N,2))
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,2))
res[0,0,:,:]= y

y = np.zeros((N,1))
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,1))
res[0,0,:,:]= y

y = np.zeros(N)
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,1))
res[0,0,:,:]= y
```

I'm getting the error for the last example but they are both (y and res) 1D vector right?

I'm wondering if it exists a solution to make this assignment whatever the size of the last dimension (1, 2 or more)?

In my code I made an try except but could exist another way

```
try:
    self.res[i,j,:,:] = self.ODE_solver(len(self.t))
except:
    self.res[i, j, :, 0] = self.ODE_solver(len(self.t))
```

Comment: and you dont know the shape of `self.ODE_solver(len(self.t))` before you initialize `self.res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the generic solution that works across all three scenarios, use -

```
res[0,0,:,:] = y.reshape(y.shape[0],-1)
```

So, basically, we are making `y` `2D` while keeping the first axis length intact and changing the second one based on the *leftover*.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape `y` to be the last 2 dimensions of `res`.

```py
N=10
y = np.zeros((N,2))
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,2))
res[0,0,:,:]= y.reshape(res.shape[-2:])

y = np.zeros((N,1))
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,1))
res[0,0,:,:]= y.reshape(res.shape[-2:])

y = np.zeros(N)
res = np.zeros((2,2,N,1))
res[0,0,:,:]= y.reshape(res.shape[-2:])
```